# where to get the history of Firefox homepage 'snippets'/links?

Tags: firefox

Ok, maybe this is a fairly pointless question - but by this, I mean the link and text that gets put into the box under your search field on about:home in more recent releases (v5, v6 & probably earlier).

The data seems to come from https://snippets.mozilla.com (via some long URL path that appears derived from your useragent string), but there doesn't seem to be any way of querying it.

..there have been some cool links pop up on there and I just *wish* I could remember them!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source code of this server lives here: https://github.com/lmorchard/home-snippets-server. Unfortunately, everything I see suggests that the content lives in an SQLite database on some server and isn't replicated to any source code repositories or such. So you can only see the snippets that are still active and you can query them with URLs like:

> `https://snippets.mozilla.com/1/Firefox/6.0.2/0/WINNT_x86-msvc/en-US/release/Windows_NT%206.1/default/default/`

I *guess* that the only fields determining which snippets you see are the browser version and locale. E.g. if you replace "en-US" by "de" you will see the German snippets - and it's a different list. Pre-release versions (currently 7.0 and beyond) get a shorter list.

Btw, by "cool links" you probably meant [this](http://forrestthroughthetrees.blogspot.com/2011/08/functionally-infused-snippet-goodness.html)?

**Edit**: You can see the localization of snippets being performed [here](https://l10n.mozilla-community.org/webdashboard/?project=2&task=Update+Home+Page+snippets). This is text only however and you cannot see "historical" content here either.

Comment: thanks, some good detective work there (: i guess we'll never know what used to be up there though!